# Change asp.net core model property name on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, swagger

I have a model

```
 public class Item
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
 }
```

i like to show the Property **ItemName** as **ServiceName** in api end point as well as in swagger. Where user will get/post the data as **ServiceName** but in the back end it will bind to **ItemName**. Other important think is **ServiceName** should be dynamic, It come from database, where if i change **ServiceName** to **ProductName** then it should bind **ProductName** to **ItemName**. I am using asp.net core 2.2 with EF core and swagger ui.

Comment: Post your trying

Comment: sorry, i don't know what to do. I didn't try anything .. although i did see some custom model binding tutorials .. if that helps ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute. It has a constructor that takes a `propertyName` string.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ServiceName")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it solve the first part of my problem, but did not solve the dynamic part ...

Comment: If you need to change "ServiceName" to "ProductName" then just change to `[JsonProperty("ProductName")]`.